# Power off requires password for all android phone

Tags: security, lock-screens, power-options, find-my-device

One of my relatives dropped their phone and someone picked it up and turned it off. Now there is no way to locate it as Find My Device does not show it anymore.

I have an Android 12 device and there are some other devices with friends and family that are running Android 12 or less.

I searched and there is a "Require password to turn off" in newer phones.

Is there a way I can implement the same feature on the devices that I have?

I am willing to root or use third-party apps for this.